# Angular : How to get user id in api authorization

Tags: angular, authorization, angular8

I have this following service code block under `authorize.service.ts` and from that return value, I can fetch the current logged in user's userName:

```
  public getUser(): Observable<IUser | null> {
    return concat(
      this.userSubject.pipe(take(1), filter(u => !!u)),
      this.getUserFromStorage().pipe(filter(u => !!u), tap(u => this.userSubject.next(u))),
      this.userSubject.asObservable());
  }
```

This is the `getUserFromStorage()` function:

```
  private getUserFromStorage(): Observable<IUser> {
    return from(this.ensureUserManagerInitialized())
      .pipe(
        mergeMap(() => this.userManager.getUser()),
        map(u => u && u.profile));
  }
```

I call this service under my login-menu.component.ts file where I get the user name as follows:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.isAuthenticated = this.authorizeService.isAuthenticated();
    this.userName = this.authorizeService.getUser().pipe(map(u => u && u.name));
  }
```

What I want is to fetch user id as well just like the way I fetch user name.

Comment: what prevents you from using something like `map(u => u && {id: u.id, name: u.name})` ?

Comment: I want to assign it to some other variable other than this.userName. However, when I apply the same approach to get id, it gives me nothing

Comment: Are you sure that the user id is actually available in the data ? This field might be hidden for security reasons. Can you `console.log(u)` and tell if you see any id here ?

Comment: Also, it seems weird that you `pipe()` but never `subscribe()`. Do you `subscribe()` somewhere later in the code ?

Comment: No, I did not use subscribe but it returns me the userName. Actually ı apply this code from the tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Under which scope should I log the u variable?

Comment: Replace `.pipe(map(u => u && u.name))` with `.pipe(map(u => {console.log(u); return u && u.name;}))`

Comment: It prints an object which contains `s_hash` and `sid` values among with the other fields. There is the userName as well, but no id.

Comment: Actually the point I could not understand how does the `getUser()` function get the userName?What does the `concat` function concatanates on `getUser()`function

Answer (score 2):

**In the component add this function.**

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.authorizeService.getUser()
    .subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data); //You will get all your user related information in this field
    });
}
```

Comment: can you put the response which you get in the console for data?

Comment: This is working as per expected. just use the object value using:-    data.name or data.sid as per your need . Access the object key .

Comment: but I want to fetch regular integer value that I am using as id field for the user table in my database. Thats some string value

Comment: canvert string to int

Comment: So, you say that that when I convert `Fal-AvSBiX0kFTWp2xt9fw` i will get some number like 1, 2, 3 ...?

Comment: No thats an alphanumberic string bro

Comment: Yeah thats what ı m trying to explain. What I store as USER ID in my database is regular integer value. That s not it

Comment: In other words that `sid` stuff is not my user id

Comment: So there is no need to convert

Comment: give me a snap of data.userid

Comment: which is the key for userid in your api service use that

Comment: Its value is undefined. I dont know why `getUser()` funciton dont give me an id